# How to avoid overlap between x ticks in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to use matplotlib to plot a dependency on dates (I use dates as X-values). As a result I get a plot with a huge number of x-ticks (dates) and these dates are overlapped such that one cannot recognize what date are there.

I read that the problem can appear of dates are not really date-objects but strings representing the dates (for example '2015-02-12'). However, I have really date-objects and it still does not work.

Here is my code:

```
plt.figure()
plt.xlim([date_1, date_2])
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.plot(df['col1'].tolist(), df['col2'].tolist(), marker = 'o')
plt.savefig(fname)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember solving this problem by telling python to plot not all the datetimes but only every n-th datetime from the huge list.

In my code I solved this in the following command:

```
ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks(datetimes[::2])
```

Notice that it's the [::2] that tells python to take every second element.

You should try different values and look what works best for you either it's 2, 50 or 200.